# AutoFill with variable As Range Failed

Tags: vba

This is my first time using `.Autofill`, but I cant figure it out.  I've looked around, and everything I have found and tried doesn't quite do it.  I think this is the closest to getting it right I've been, but I may be mistaken.  I'm trying to use `.Autofill` to populate a column but I will have a `For` loop before each `.Autofill`, so I can't do it all at once.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets(1)
Dim EquationRange As Range
Dim DestinationRange As Range
Dim RowNumber As Long
    RowNumber = 2

Set EquationRange = ws.Cells(RowNumber, 1)
Set DestinationRange = ws.Cells(RowNumber + 1, 1)

EquationRange.AutoFill Destination:=DestinationRange
```

I started out with `Dim ws As Worksheet` and just `Set EquationRange = Cells(RowNumber, 1)` but when I searched similar questions for a solution they all specified `Worksheets()`, but that didn't work.  I keep getting the error

> AutoFill Method of Range class Failed

When I inspect the code while in break mode it says that `DestinationRange = Empty`, but when I used `Debug.Print DestinationRange.Address(False, False)` it gave the right output.  What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting error bcoz "**The destination must include the source range**". Refer the [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195345.aspx). So, your code should be something as below

```
Private Sub test()
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim EquationRange As Range
  Dim DestinationRange As Range
  Dim RowNumber As Long

  Set ws = Worksheets(1)
  RowNumber = 2

  With ws
    Set EquationRange = .Range(.Cells(RowNumber, 1))
    Set DestinationRange = .Range(.Cells(RowNumber, 1), .Cells(RowNumber + 1, 1))
  End With

  EquationRange.AutoFill Destination:=DestinationRange

End Sub
```

Comment: I was just looking over this again, and I was wondering why you put `.Cells()` within `.Range()` in `Set EquationRange = .Range(.Cells(RowNumber, 1))`?  I understand that for `DestinationRange` it is required for more than one cell.  Is if for uniformity, or is there another reason?

Comment: no reason for it... i was trying out different steps to understand your problem and it was left to be changed.